# Are there performance downsides for using only expressions / no statements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance, expression, code-translation

I'm working in translating a huge amount of code of certain language to JavaScript. My work would be considerably easier if I translated everything as expressions, without statements. For example, instead of

```
f = function(a,b){
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    if (a>5)
        return a+b;
    else
        return a*b;
};
console.log(f(2,2));
```

I would have:

```
f = function(a,b){
    return console.log(a), console.log(b), (a>5?a+b:a*b);
};
```

Except I'm worried that less human-like code will probably be optimized worse. Is this worry valid?

Note: the code wouldn't be readable in either ways.

Comment: I think this needs the information whether you mean server-side or browser-side JavaScript?

Comment: I think you meant `return console.log(a), console.log(b), (a>5?a+b:a*b);`.

Comment: thats just replacing an if else, with a ternary ...  I would guess the difference is neglible in execution speeds.

Comment: The answer is going to be: **It depends**. It depends on the JavaScript engine that will be processing the result. Some engines may handle the comma expression *better* than the `if/else` statement. Others worse.

Comment: Benchmark it, there's really no telling given that there are a  number of JavaScript engine out there. Try it out in the browser/engines that you cared about.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/checkperf1 The second one seemed to run faster on chrome for me.

Comment: @LieRyan the problem is coming up with a meaningful benchmark. That is, one that will evaluate the performances differences of changing between those styles across a normal program. Not sure how I could do that.

Comment: @Cthulhu barely slower for me, but I don't think that code would show a difference? I'm worried in changing it across the entire source code, but I'm a little less worried now from the reactions here.

Comment: @Dokkat There seems to be something else wrong. The second function returns `undefined`!

Comment: @Dokkat: Well, I didn't like to assume I hadn't missed a subtlety.

Comment: Certain minifiers do statement to expression conversion to save bytes. Minifiers are used to speed up loading the file, so if there would be a severe execution slowdown, then nobody would be using those minifiers.

Comment: @Cthulhu are you sure? Just tested it. Which engine are you using?

Comment: @Cthulhu: The corrected version works fine, returns `4` for the inputs `2, 2`.

Comment: Benchmarking this is completely futile, the console.logs take 99.999% of the runtime so the difference cannot be seen.

Comment: @pimvdb good point, thanks!

Comment: Chrome script console. Ohh wait, it is fine. The undef is returned at the end anyway. It collapsed the two `2`'s it received in the second case. Weird.

Comment: I think the only real danger is getting infatuated with having them all over the place, and you end up overworking your code in ways that it's at best debatable it's any better off, at worst, messy or oddly structured. It's fun, though, to see how far you can take it.

Answer (score 1):

> Except I'm worried that less human-like code will probably be
>   optimized worse. Is this worry valid?

In a nutshell, no. I'm picking future maintenance is your concern over execution speed. If future programmers working on this have not come across (a>b?a:b;) they will quickly pick it up and probably thank you for far more concise code.

In the same vein, I would be more concerned with the return function you have given. I am admittedly only just picking up js (Java background), but

```
return console.log(a), console.log(b), (a>5?a+b:a*b);
```

it is less intuitive than

```
console.log(a); console.log(b); return (a>5?a+b:a*b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Personly I would go with this one

```
var f = function(a, b){
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    return ( a > 5 ? a + b : a * b);
};
```

using this on the client side  will reduce the file size by few bytes

Comment: No, actually the problem is the function body, which is a different construct in relation to the language I'm translating from.